# Graphene to phoneme heuristic for OOV words

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I need to do Graphene to phoneme (g2p) conversion in c++, however, most g2p libraries are in python or rust (pocketsphinx might work but seems like a headache).

G2P is done by:

- Dictionary lookup for non-homophones.
- calculates POS for homophones
- deep learning for OOV (out of vocabulary) words

However, for now it doesn't matter if there's vowel substitution for homophones and OOV words.

I just need to get my other code up and running, and then I can forget about this disaster, so a quick heuristic is what's needed.

I'd post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt https://godbolt.org/z/z6G4o6c4K

It pronounces `school` as `s-chul` (in arpabet `S CH UW L`). But that's good enough I suppose.

It first tries to parse the first two characters, if they match common digram (i.e. `ch`, `sh`, `th`) then return the corresponding phoneme and pass the remainder. Otherwise convert the first letter to the closest phoneme.